# Acessar valores dentro de um array a partir do índice

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Eu possuo uma variável `x` com o seguinte conteúdo dentro:

```
x = [ {
    id: '1',
    name: 'name,
} ]
```

E achei que para acessar o `id` fosse `x.id`, porém, não é assim. Como acessar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aí tem um objeto dentro de um *array*. Primeiro você acessa o índice do elemento (no caso só tem um, então é `0`), depois acessa o membro do objeto, como fez corretamente.

```js
var x = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'name',
}]
console.log(x[0].id);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Index.js).

Na atribuição de um valor os colchetes delimitam um *array*. As chaves delimitam um objeto.

Só como curiosidade também funcionaria `x[0]["id"]` já que em JavaScript um objeto na verdade é um *array* associativo.